PAM config issue trying to differentiate Google Authenticator secret based on root user
I have setup Google Authenticator PAM lib - on login I am trying to differentiate the secret file location based on root compared to other users. So far the below modification to /etc/pam.d/sshd allows others users to be challenged with a Verification code on login as normal but for user root is only getting challenged for a password even though the auth log is listing 'requirement "user = root" was met by user "root"'.
/etc/pam.d/sshd:
# Root user
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user = root
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_google_authenticator.so debug secret=/root/.google_authenticator

# Non-root users
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user != root
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so debug secret=/home/%u/key/.google_authenticator

How do I get this to work for root user?
